# How to remove \n of fgets function, without using string functions

Tags: c

Is there a way to remove the \N character from the end of the string reading with fgets, without using string processing functions (strlen, strtok, strcspn, etc) ?
I tried that, but it doesn't work

```
char* remove_newline_char(char *str){
    for(int i = 0; i < str[i]; i++){
        if(str[i] == '\n'){
            str[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the condition `i < str[i]` to yout [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
ahhhhhh, I just realized what I did ..., thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course it had to be that way int i = 0; str[i]; i++

Comment: Don't add "fixed" to the title. Instead press the checkmark next to the best answer below, or, if there's no good answer, post your own and mark it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is semantically incorrect.  the loop termination expression `i < str[i]` says:

> is the string index less than the character value at that index?

which is of course nonsense - the index and the character value are unrelated.

```
char* remove_newline_char(char* str)
{
    int i = 0 ;
    while( str[i] != 0 && str[i] != '\n' )
    {
        i++ ;
    }
    str[i] = 0 ;

    return str ;
}
```

Given that this processing is specific to buffers populated by `fgets()` rather then a generic string function, there may be merit in combining the input with the processing so that it will not be applied to inappropriate strings (i.e. not from `fgets()`):

```
char* freadline( char* str, int num, FILE* stream )
{
    char* ret = NULL ;

    if( (ret = fgets( str, num, str )) != NULL )
    {
        int i = 0 ;
        while( str[i] != 0 && str[i] != '\n' )
        {
            i++ ;
        }
        str[i] = 0 ;
     }
     return ret ;
}
```

Comment: `freadline()` need not repeatedly test `str[i] != '\n'` in a loop.  Only one test, after the loop needed. `if (i > 0 && str[i - 1] == '\n') str[i-1] = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to transverse through the full array and check for each character at every iteration.

As, you have stated *don't use string functions*, I'm not using `strlen()` function.

In `fgets()` newline character is present at `length - 1` position.

```c
char* remove_newline_char(char *str){
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len])
        len++;
    if(len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n')
        str[len - 1] = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Also, if you know the length of string, then you can avoid that `while` loop

```c
char* remove_newline_char(char *str, size_t len){
    if(len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n')
        str[len - 1] = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course my loop was wrong. Here's the version that works

```
char* remove_newline_char(char *str){
for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
    if(str[i] == '\n'){
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
}
return str;
```

}

Comment: If you fix it that way, you are running to the end of the original string when you only need to run until `\n` - a minor issue in the case of `fgets()` populated strings perhaps, but your function could be presented with strings not from `fgets()`.